# Sharing Folder Between 2 Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

I have a physical Windows 2008 R2 Server box and need to share a folder on this server to be visible on an Amazon AWS Windows 2012 server. They are on the same VPN tunnel.

I have created a shared folder on the 2008 Physical box: C:/Share
Let's say the physical box is on 192.22.22.222

How would I get the Amazon AWS Server to see this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if server1=192.168.0.20 and server2=192.168.0.30 and you share a folder C:\Share on server1 (and didn't set $ after the share name) you should be able to reach it by typing: \\192.168.0.20\Share from your server 2 (win explorer).

Comment: So, it says that 192.168.0.20 is not responding.. any ideas?

Comment: for testing purpose, are you able to disable both firewall and test again? (are you sure that they are able to communicate between eachother?) don't do this if its a production env

Comment: Pretty sure this is the correct answer.. I think there is a networking issue I am dealing with.